# Using On Duplicate Key Update with an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to MYSQL and am having trouble combining idea I have read about. I have a form generated from a query. I want to be able to insert or update depending on whether there is currently a matching row. I have the following code which works for inserting but I;m struggling with the On DUPLICATE UPDATE part I keep getting a message saying there is an error in my syntax or unexpeted ON depending on how I put the ' .

```
 require_once("connect_db.php"); 

    $row_data = array();
    foreach($_POST['attendancerecordid'] as $row=>$attendancerecordid) {
    $attendancerecordid=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$attendancerecordid);
    $employeeid=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_POST['employeeid'][$row]));
    $linemanagerid=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_POST['linemanagerid'][$row]));
    $abscencecode=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_POST['abscencecode'][$row]));
    $date=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_POST['date'][$row]));



    $row_data[] = "('$attendancerecordid', '$employeeid', '$linemanagerid', '$abscencecode', '$date')";
    }
    if (!empty($row_data)) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO attendance (attendancerecord, employeeid, linemanagerid, abscencecode, date) VALUES '.implode(',', $row_data) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abscencecode = $row_data[abscencecode];
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error ($dbc));
    }
```

The various echo statements are showing that the correct data is coming through and my select statement was as expected before I added in the ON DUPLICATE statement.

Comment: What does `echo $sql` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the way the sql statement is constructed via string concatenation. When you create an sql statement, echo it and run it in your favourite mysql manager app for testing.

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO attendance (attendancerecord, employeeid, linemanagerid, abscencecode, date) VALUES ('.implode(',', $row_data).') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abscencecode = 1'; //1 is a fixed value yiu choose
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that your $row_data array does not have named keys, it just contains the entire new rows values as string. Since you do bulk insert (multiple rows inserted in 1 statement), you have to provide a single absencecode in the on duplicate key clause, or you have to execute each row in a separate insert to get the absence code for each row in a loop.

Comment: Now I get:
Notice: Use of undefined constant abscencecode - assumed 'abscencecode' in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\PacificaHR\attendancesubmit.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: abscencecode in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\PacificaHR\attendancesubmit.php on line 19

Comment: That's a notice only and I updated my answer earlier to use $row_data['abscencecode'] instead of $row_data[abscencecode]. The more important question is: does my suggested solution generate the right sql statement for you?

Comment: The SQL statement is still erroring in a not very helpful way: INSERT INTO attendance (attendancerecord, employeeid, linemanagerid, abscencecode, date) VALUES (('2015-09-18-1', '1', '20', '1', '2015-10-13'),('2015-09-18-22', '22', '20', '2', '2015-10-13'),('2015-09-18-242', '242', '20', '7', '2015-10-13')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abscencecode = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: You need to provide us with your updated code and the exact sql statement you tried to execute. The above sql code is definitely not the full one, unless you missed the absence code from the end of it.

Comment: Updated Code: $row_data[] = "('$attendancerecordid', '$employeeid', '$linemanagerid', '$abscencecode', '$date')";
}
if (!empty($row_data)) {
$sql = 'INSERT INTO attendance (attendancerecord, employeeid, linemanagerid, abscencecode, date) VALUES ('.implode(',', $row_data).') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abscencecode = '.$row_data['abscencecode'];
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error ($dbc));
}

Comment: The output above was what my browser gave me when it pinted the sql statement and then executed the SQL statement

Comment: Then you are obviously missing the absence code from the end of the statement. Plus you have extra () around the values clause. Probably the 2 things are related, you have multiple rows in the $row_data array.

Comment: I've removed the extra ( ) from the values but it's still the same issue in that it doesnt put the end of the statement on. I've tried changing the ' to " but it makes no difference. There's definitly the correct number of ' .  $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (attendancerecord, employeeid, linemanagerid, abscencecode, attendancedate) VALUES ".implode(',', $row_data)." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abscencecode=" .$row_data['abscencecode'];

Comment: Still you are missing the absencecode value from the end.

Comment: yeah - I cant figure out how to make it put the abscence code from the row of the array that it is currently looping through in there. abscencecode=" .$row_data['abscencecode'] isnt putting it in- it just stops.